How can the A* algorithm revisit the same node twice in multi-agent pathfinding(MAPF)?
I am attempting to solve a MAPF-like problem using the Conflict-Based Search (CBS) algorithm. My specific problem is based on a grid graph where some edges are not connected.
For example, in the figure below, agent A needs to travel from node 1 to node 4, while agent B needs to move from node 4 to node 1.
In CBS, the low-level algorithm (A*) is used to find paths in a time-space network. We can identify that the two agents will conflict at time t = 2 . To resolve this, we add a constraint for agent A, preventing it from visiting node 5 at t = 2 . Consequently, agent A can visit node 2 at t = 2 .
However, agent A cannot return to node 3 at t = 3 because node 3 is in the closed list.

I have two ideas regarding this issue:
(a) Reopen node 3 for agent A. (b) Treat (node 3, t=2) and (node 3, t=3) as two different nodes.
However, idea (a) introduces a series of decisions to determine whether a move is a giveway action. Idea (b) expands the search space due to the added time dimension.
Does anyone have any suggestions, instructions, or related papers on this topic? Thank you very much!

Option b is the way I've solved this in the past. With a good heuristic, A* won't explore too much of the expanded search space.

Hi, DMGregory! Thank you for your answers and links. I will have a try.
